# jQuery & Stored Sortable Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

OK so I was using jquery 1.8.3 to sort a page list order that's pulled from /pages/order
what this would allow you to do was drag and drop the pages in what ever order you liked, then a menu was presented on the template view end from pages order.
First it started with list items then I thought it better to use tabletools as this had a great search function. That all worked fine.

Now I wanted to update because I setup a bootstrap 3 template for backend and frontend. I recently just tried updating to bootstrap3 and got tabletools working great with bootstrap in examples, however I can't for the life of me get sortable rows to work. There is a plugin called Row Reordering that again, I can't seem to get to work. Any help would be seriously appreciated.

Using:

```
jquery v2.1.0,
Bootstrap v3.1.1,
DataTables v1.9.4
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZHJg/)

Comment: You'll get more responses, if you can provide an example.. on something say [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I thought an example would not be needed as it's just a simple row order ? ( Me being a 'numpty' can't figure it out)